# C# showdialog window stays at the back of main window sometimes

Tags: c#, windows, focus, showdialog

I have a main window where there is a text-box when the user clicks C in the text-box another small window opened as showdialog appears with information, problem is sometimes it opens but a few times it goes behind the main form where you cant see it and cannot even access it seems like the main form becomes the showdialog instead. also a few times if a windows folder is open in the background than that folder comes in front of my program on the screen when the C is clicked in the text-box, but the focus stays on the program. its a real struggle i have been looking into this for long time, i cannot seem to find the issue.

i have tried bringtofront(), Activate() but does not work in any case showdialog window should always be on top of parent window.

here is my code:

```
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && txtQauntity.Text != "" && (txtForm.Text == "Cash Sale" | txtForm.Text == "Debtors Cash Sale" | txtForm.Text == "Debtors Account Sale" | txtForm.Text == "New Laybye"))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

                using (var frm = new frmQuotation(this))
                {
                    
                    frm.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.gbProductDetails.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.gbDispute.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    
                    frm.chkDispute.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtSellIncl.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtPriceDate.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtOnOrder.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtOnhand.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtMininumLvl.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtMarkup.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtLastReceived.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtLastQtyGrv.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtItemRating.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtItemCode.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtDisputeReason.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtDisputeDate.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtDesc.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtCostIncl.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtCode.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.gbCredentials.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtuser.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.txtPass.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                    frm.Size = new Size(953, 650);
                    frm.txtItemCode.Focus();
                    frm.ActiveControl = frm.txtItemCode;
                    
                    frm.Activate();
                    frm.BringToFront();
                    frm.ShowDialog(this); // this is where the window opens
```

Comment: Is the main form a topmost=true window?

Comment: @CaiusJard no it is false